# Se puede poner en codigo zpl el tamaño de una etiqueta?

Tags: zebra, zpl

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es un ejemplo de una etiqueta que manejamos.

Ahora, se creo un software de etiquetas  que se genera por medio de los ZPL que ocupemos, el cual utilizamos  otro software antiguo que se llama Label Matrix por el cual con ese programa extraemos el código ZPL, mi duda es esta, se puede poner en código zpl las medidas de las etiquetas sin necesidad de utilizar el Matrix, ya que con ese se crea la etiqueta con las medida y solo se extrae el codigo y se cambian las variables ejemplo

^XA^PRB^FS
^MSY^FO250,11^A0N,17,15^FD(11S) PN SN:^FS
^FO390,11^A0N,17,15^FD@right12serie1^FS
^FO330,11^A0N,18,16^FD@customerassy^FS
^FO250,68^A0N,17,15^FDEC: @eco^FS
^FO470,68^A0N,17,15^FDfecham2/d2/y2^FS
^FO250,86^A0N,17,15^FDMade in Mexico^FS
^BY1,2.0^FS
^FO250,30^B3N,N,33,N,N^FD@serie1^FS
^BY1,2.0^FS
^PQ1,0,1,Y^XZ^XA^XZ

uso la pagina http://labelary.com/viewer.html para darme el previo del código.

En fin mi pregunta es esa, se puede poder el  tamaño de la etiqueta en el zpl, ya que cuando por algún motivo o rara la circunstancia  la cual no se cual sea el problema si cambiamos de impresora todo se mueve y tengo que ajustar las coordenadas para que salgan en la impresora, pero vaya sorpresa, al dia siguiente salen  movidas y tengo que volver ajustar de nuevo las coordenadas; espero darme a entender.